# Why "proxy_pass_header Server;"

Tags: nginx

I'm just starting on NGINX, and I have seen in several example configs that people use

```
proxy_pass_header    Server;
```

when proxy-ing the request to an upstream server? What exactly does it do here? What are the possible use cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's telling the nginx service to pass the upstream's `Server` header instead of putting its own in the response.  It's essentially cosmetic.

Answer (score 6):

This is required for compliance with HTTP/1.1 which states that [Server is an origin header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.38):

> If the response is being forwarded through a proxy, the proxy application **MUST NOT** modify the Server response-header. Instead, it SHOULD include a Via field